# Having a shell with console connection without using the physical port in Linux system

Tags: console, serial-port, serial-console, virtual-consoles

A program starts when you are connected to Linux by console port. Otherwise, it refuses to start.
I have to connect to my server remotely by SSH connection. I'm looking for a way to do something to solve this problem. Is there any way to start a new shell by ttyS* port when you are connecting by SSH? (without physically connecting to console port and just using ethernet port by SSH.)

I have tested simple solutions and none of them worked: using "cat" and "echo" for the file descriptor (ttyS*) didn't work. Using picocom and "screen" command to connect to serial port didn't work.
And I'm not sure null-modem emulator (packages like tty0tty) could solve my problem or not.

I appreciate any ideas to help solve this problem.

Comment: You really should tell answerers what "a program" is, what your [console](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/linux-console.xml) is configured to be, _how_ the "a program" has been configured in order to use this device, and exactly _how_ it "refuses to start"; and clarify your scattershot tagging because a _serial port_ is not _necessarily_ the console and definitely isn't a [virtual terminal](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/linux-vt.xml) or indeed a _virtual_ anything.

Comment: Yes, you are right @JdeBP. It is a networking program and when I start its debugging shell, it prints that it can be accessed just on "console". when I was able to reach the physical location of the server, I  have tested this debugging feature by console connection and it worked properly. The "ttyS1" serial port was used for that connection.
The configuration: BOOT_IMAGE=/kernel-3.16-lts-x86_64-all nopat console=ttyS1,115200n8

Comment: All that I want is some trick which changes a terminal connection type to ttyS1, from pts/1, for instance.